# Why is the entire syntax not entered when entering Excel data -> pptx?

Tags: powerpoint, python-pptx

Why is the entire syntax not entered when entering Excel data -> pptx?
I want to put all the data in each column in Excel as pptx, slide.placeolders.text.
However, it comes out properly with the print function, but when you actually print it out with pptx, only one data is properly printed.
and the rest of the data is not output. Why?

```
num = 0
num2 = df.shape[0]
while num < num2 -1 :
    num= num + 1
    slide.placeholders[19].text = df.name[num]+'\n'+df.doc1[num]
    print(slide.placeholders[19].text)

    if df.name[num] is NULL :
       break
```

what's wrong?

[excel data]
name/doc1

a/1
b/2
c/3

[print result]

a 1
b 2
c 3

but pptx result

a 1

Comment: Are you using python-pptx to do this? If so you/I can tag it with python-pptx and you might get answers from people who otherwise wouldn't see it.

Comment: oh~THANK YOU^^, i did not  know it.

Comment: What happens if you break the text up at the  \n characters and add each line as a run?